# Recursively dividing up square regions

Tags: java, recursion, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to divide square into 4 smaller quadrants by randomly selecting a point in the square and drawing two lines through it, and then dividing each of those quadrants up into 4, and so on, until the width/height is 1, in a *recursive* way. My code is here:

```
public static void draw(int x0, int y0, int xmax, int ymax) {

if (Math.abs(xmax - x0) > 1 && Math.abs(ymax - y0) > 1) {
    int rx = r.nextInt(xmax - 1) + 1;    // line A
    int ry = r.nextInt(ymax - 1) + 1;    // line B

    StdDraw.line(rx, y0, rx, ymax);
    StdDraw.line(x0, ry, xmax, ry);

    draw(x0, y0, rx, ry);        // line C
    draw(x0, ry, rx, ymax);      // line D
    draw(rx, ry, xmax, ymax);    // line E
    draw(rx, y0, xmax, ry);      // line F
}
else ;
```

That is, I'm passing the lower left corner coordinates (x0, y0) and the upper right corner coordinates (xmax, ymax). Whenever I comment out lines D, E, and F, everything works fine. But when I uncomment any of D, E, or F, I get this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive`, usually pointed at line A or line B. Can someone please tell me what this error means and how I can fix it?

Comment: Normally when dealing with drawing lines to the screen, (xMax,yMax) is the upper left corner and (x2,y2) is the lower right.

Comment: @ColinD what do you mean by "normally?" I didn't think it mattered since I control the start and end points of the drawn line

Comment: I edited my comment incorrectly, it should read (x0,y0) then (xMax, yMax). I was just trying to point out that in order to work with graphics libraries your coordinates might need translation. Also, since the code snippet does not clearly identify which APIs you are using it could have been part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that `nextInt(int n)` seems to contain the only `n` variable in that piece of code it is likely the one that is throwing that error.

Make sure that `xmax-1` and `ymax-1` don't become negative as the documentation for `nextInt` specifically says it throws this error on negative numbers:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

This is because somewhere during your recursion the value passed in `nextInt` -> `(xmax - 1)`is becoming negative.

```
r.nextInt(xmax - 1);
```

If `(xmax - 1)` is negative you will get exception.  Because, `nextInt()` method takes only `positive` values.

- You can add an additional check before this line to check whether
  your difference is negative or positive. And accordingly, you can
  skip this part of code.